# Redirecting an output of Plink produces an empty file

Tags: batch-file, plink

I'm programming a short batch file that opens `plink` and redirects the output to a log file. But my log file is empty. Any advice please?

```
start plink.exe -serial %COM_DEVICE% -sercfg xxxxx,8,n,1,N -v > %CD%\log\tmpLog.log
```

Answer (score 2):

The `start` opens the command (the `plink.exe`) in a new console.

The redirection redirects an output of the `start`, which is none.

It does not look like you actually need the `start` command for anything. Remove it:

```
plink.exe -serial %COM_DEVICE% -sercfg xxxxx,8,n,1,N -v > %CD%\log\tmpLog.log
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use the START command to spawn it to another process because you want your batch file to continue to run then use cmd.exe to run the process.

```
start "" cmd /c "plink.exe -serial %COM_DEVICE% -sercfg xxxxx,8,n,1,N -v > %CD%\log\tmpLog.log"
```

Answer (score -2):

after modification as below:

```
plink.exe -serial %COM_DEVICE% -sercfg 19200,8,n,1,N -v > %CD%\log\tmpLog.log 2>&1
```

I removed `start` and add `2>&1`
it's working, thank yall